# Delay In Response While Selecting Multiple Images From Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android

I am selecting multiple images from Intent.ACTION_PICK.  After selecting about 20 images and clicking on the tick mark on top right, there is a **delay for about 5-10 seconds**.  During this delay there is no progress dialog or toast.  It gives the impression that the app has hanged which is bad for UX.  The code works fine, images get sent,  only the **delay "suspense"** is bad.  Is there any way to give a toast, alert or progress bar after clicking the tick and before coming onActivity result.  Following is my code.

**Intent To Choose**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,
                true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                            "Select Picture"),
                       RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

**On Activity Result**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                             int resultCode,
                             Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).RESULT_OK) {

        // For Uploading Multiple Files
        if (data.getClipData() != null || data.getData() != null) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On how many devices or emulators did you test?

Comment: Try without createChooser.

Comment: Tried on Xiaomi Redme 5 and 5 Pro, and without chooser startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE); still the same

Comment: maybe with async task?

Comment: Async task makes no sense. Try on phones which have not Xiaomi/Chinese spy software.

Comment: should we also ask all the users of our app to stop buying Xiaomi/Chinese phones...